# Android Sprite Animation Move To position X (should be simple but, I'm stuck)

Tags: java, android, animation, view, sprite

I'm trying to move sprites to stop the frames in center(or move them to certain x position) when right or left pressed on screen. There are 3 sprites created using box.java in the view, placed one after another with padding, stored in arraylist.

**The problem:** No smooth movement and doesn't stop in the center of each frames after movement has begun, sometimes all boxes are moving on top of each others, padding is totally lost. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong, thanks a lot!

```
//BEGINING OF BOX.JAVA >> The problem is in this class!

//This goes in Update();
private void boxMove()
{
           int get_moved_pos = getMovedPos();   //get moved pos
           int sprite_size = view.getSpriteSize(); //get sprite arraylist size
           currentDirection = view.getDirection(); //get direction "left" or "right" from view

                if(currentDirection == "right" && isMoving == false)
                {
                        setSpriteMovedNext();
                }else
                if(currentDirection == "left" && isMoving == false)
                {
                        setSpriteMovedPrev();
                }

                if(currentDirection != lastDirection)
                {
                            lastDirection = currentDirection;

                            //MOVE RIGHT
                            if(currentDirection == "right" && get_moved_pos > 0)    //move left and make sure that moved pos isn't overlapping / or moving to empty space
                            {

                                //Animate left until it reaches the new x position                  
                                if(x > get_new_pos_left)
                                {
                                    x -= pSpeedX;
                                }

                                Log.d("RIGHT","POS: " + get_moved_pos);

                            }else

                            //MOVE LEFT
                            if(currentDirection == "left" && get_moved_pos < sprite_size-1) //move left and make sure that moved pos isn't overlapping / or moving to empty space
                            {
                                //Animate right until it reaches the new x position                 
                                if(x < get_new_pos_right)
                                {
                                    x += pSpeedX;
                                }

                            }
                }


}

        //Call when screen is touched (in View.java), to set a new position to move to.
       public void resetMoving()
       {
           isMoving = false;
            this.lastDirection      = "";
           Log.d("RESET", "MOVING RESET");
       }

       public int getMovedPos()
       {
           return this.smoved_pos;
       }


       private void setSpriteMovedNext()
       {
           int get_max_moved = getMovedPos();
           int s_size = view.getSpriteSize();

           if (isMoving == false) //take a break between movements
           {
                if(get_max_moved < s_size-1)
                {
                    Log.d("NEXT", "CALLED");
                    this.get_new_pos_right  = x + view.getNextPosX();   //current x and next stop position
                    this.smoved_pos     += 1;
                    this.isMoving       = true; //set to avoid double touch
                    Log.d("NEXT", "X POS SET: " + get_max_moved);
                }
           }
       }

       private void setSpriteMovedPrev()
       {
           int get_max_moved = getMovedPos();

           if (isMoving == false) //take a break between movements
           {
               if(get_max_moved > 0)
               {
                   Log.d("PREV", "CALLED");
                   this.get_new_pos_left    = x - view.getNextPosX(); //get current x pos and prev stop position
                   this.smoved_pos          -= 1;   //to limit the movements
                   this.isMoving            = true; //set to avoid double touch
                   Log.d("PREV", "X POS SET: " + get_max_moved);
               }
           }
       }
```

//END OF BOX.JAVA

//VIEW

```
   //Add boxes
   public void addBox()
   {
       int TOTAL_BOXES = 3;
       int padding_left = 200;
       int padding_tmp =  this.getWidth()/2;

       box.clear(); //clear old

       //Box 1
       box.add(new Boxes(box, this, "box1", 
               padding_tmp,
               this.getHeight()/2, 
               boxSpriteImage, 1, 2, 0, 0));       

       padding_tmp += boxSpriteImage.getWidth()/TOTAL_BOXES + padding_left;

       //Box 2
       box.add(new Boxes(box, this, "box2", 
               padding_tmp, 
               this.getHeight()/2, 
               boxSpriteImage, 1, 2, 1, 1));       

       padding_tmp += boxSpriteImage.getWidth()/TOTAL_BOXES + padding_left;

       //Box 3
       box.add(new Boxes(box, this, "box3", 
               padding_tmp, 
               this.getHeight()/2, 
               boxSpriteImage, 1, 2, 2, 1));       

   }

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
     if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastClick > 100){
            lastClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
            synchronized (getHolder()) 
            {

            if(isBoxWindow() == true)
            {

                if(x >= this.getWidth()/2)
                {
                    Direction = "right";
                }else
                {
                    Direction = "left";
                } 
    }
        }
 }

//called in box.java to get next x pos to move
public float getNextPosX()
{
       int PADDING = 200; //padding between frames
       next_pos_x = boxSprite.getWidth()/TOTAL_COLUMNS + PADDING;
       return next_pos_x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is in the `if` statements, where you compare `currentDirection` and `lastDirection` (I'm assuming that `lastDirection` is a `String`) with other `String`s using the `==` operator. The `==` almost operator never works when you want to compare `Object`s for equality. You should use the `equals()` method.

For eg.

```
if(currentDirection != lastDirection)
```

should be written as:

```
if(!currentDirection.equals(lastDirection)
```

Make such changes in your code(They are needed at many places!) and I think your problem should be solved.

A good debugging practice would be logging data about your app, from each of the if blocks, to see if each of them is executed. You could have found out if your `if` statements are being executed.

**EDIT:** Why have you put this code?

```
if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastClick > 100)
```

This means `onTouchEvent`s are only interpreted after 100ms. remove it and check, probably that's what is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply udiboy, I've changed direction variables to integers, but still same result, they are moving like 5 pixels (left or right) and then it stops. (but, let me test more..)

Comment: I have added above line to have a break between touches, removed that didn't help. I think the problems are some variable im setting it as global which should be set as local(not sure). My second guess would be this line; if(currentDirection != lastDirection), since it's on the loop under the Update() and animation stops right after it detects current direction is the last direction, since it's set right after the IF check point. Sick of this, but testing more.

Comment: Ok, I've got the movements working; it moves only right or left, but doesn't move more than once. Now the case is, if left is pressed, it requires to press the right one, but 3rd box/frame is hidden since movements are limited and dislocated (moves from one end to another end without stopping in center of moved frame). Trying some more.

Comment: Im not really getting how you are trying to move the boxes? Do you want the box to move to where the user touches? what does "stop in the center of moved frame" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Alrite, decided to use onFling() method and call via View instead of adding the animations separately into the class itself, works really well when called box.get(i).update() in a loop of all added boxes, all of them animated equally. Thanks udiboy.